# Product factor in R. What's the interpretation?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, interaction

So I am reading an R guide which tells me that the product factor $B \times T$ is implemented in $R$ by using the $*$-operator on the factors after $\sim$. However, when I check the model matrix for this model, I don't quite understand it. I thought the product factor model would contain one mean value for each product $(b_i,t_j)$? Since each observation only fits into one of these groups, the model matrix should have rows which only contain a 1 in a single spot, and zeros everywhere else (assuming no intercept), yet that's not what I am seeing? What's R doing?

I have added a $-1$ after the $B*T$ in $lm$ in order to remove the intercept.

Comment: What *are* you seeing?

Comment: I am seeing something that looks like linear regression. Actually, it looks like what's said in the answer below. But I am not using numericals, but categorial factors. I have also used "factor(A)*factor(B)" to let R know this, but same result.

Comment: This is still a bit to vague to really help, unfortunately.  It would be useful if you pasted in some output, and try to point to precisely what you are finding surprising about it.  It would be especially useful for you to focus on what you *expect* to see.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I have answered your question, based on a comment to a previous answer that seems to have been removed since I saw it. Please edit your question to include the information you provided there: that you were using race and gender as categorical variables and that you were expecting to see averages of each combination of those categories in the results. That will help others understand what the problem was. Again, there is no real difference between a factor model and linear regression with dummy numeric variables, as provided by `lm`. Displaying the model matrix would help.

Answer (score 3):

From your question and your comment on an answer by @AntoniParellada, I gather that your confusion comes from the default dummy treatment coding used by R for categorical variables. Although many statistics texts present ANOVA models in terms of grand means and deviations among groups around means, as in the description of your model in your comment, that is not the default in R.

Unless you tell it otherwise, R codes a k-level factor effectively as (k-1) numeric (0,1) variables, representing whether the factor has the reference level (all k-1 of these are 0), or a 1 representing the particular non-reference level of the factor. That is the default specification of the contrasts matrix. (Regression with such numerical predictors is effectively the same as other approaches to ANOVA you might have seen.)

So in the example in your comment, if black and female are the reference levels of your factor variables, then the intercept in your model (which you shouldn't remove in this case) is the value of the outcome variable for black females, and the regression coefficients for gender and race are the differences of male versus female and white versus black, respectively. Interaction terms are similarly differences from the corresponding combinations of individual effects. In this case, the (gender x race) interaction would be the difference of the white male outcome variable from that predicted by the individual gender and race coefficients alone.

Many other types of coding schemes are possible, as described on [this page](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm), if you wish to specify them.

Comment: Since I had been working on it, I decided to simplify, and repost with categorical variables. The author of the OP appears to have un-subscribed in the meantime, but now it may splice nicely as an illustration of your more conceptual answer... or not...

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what R does. Take for example the OLS regression of miles-per-gallon consumed by vehicle regressed over the weight and qsec specs:

```
fit = lm(mpg ~ wt * qsec, mtcars)
model.matrix(fit)
                    (Intercept)    wt  qsec  wt:qsec
Mazda RX4                     1 2.620 16.46 43.12520
Mazda RX4 Wag                 1 2.875 17.02 48.93250
Datsun 710                    1 2.320 18.61 43.17520
Hornet 4 Drive                1 3.215 19.44 62.49960
...                           ...
```

Please follow-up on specific questions, but I think it is clear that R is doing exactly what it is specified in the model:

$\hat Y=\hat \beta_0+\hat \beta_1X_1+\hat\beta_2X_2+\hat \beta_3X_1*X_2+\epsilon$.

You could possibly find of help [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/185613/67822), or [this](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/lm_interactions_output_interpretation.html).

---

As for the case with categorical variables, let me illustrate with a toy dataset. Self-explanatory: just a few points of income ($1,000) versus gender and background:

```
  income sex bg
1    156   M  W
2    185   M  W
3    105   M NW
4    115   M NW
5     95   F  W
6     78   F  W
7     67   F NW
8     74   F NW
```

Here are the cross-tabulated means:

[image]

This model can be reproduced with the interaction linear model call in R `mod.inter = lm(income ~ sex * bg)`. The model matrix is:

```
model.matrix(mod.inter)
  (Intercept) sexM bgW sexM:bgW
1           1    1   1        1
2           1    1   1        1
3           1    1   0        0
4           1    1   0        0
5           1    0   1        0
6           1    0   1        0
7           1    0   0        0
8           1    0   0        0
```

Notice that the dummy-coded `sexM == 1` and `bgW == 1` these are multiplied to code the interaction `sexM:bgW == 1`, effectively creating an extra regressor.

The output coefficients are:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   70.500      8.941   7.885   0.0014 **
sexM          39.500     12.644   3.124   0.0354 * 
bgW           16.000     12.644   1.265   0.2744   
sexM:bgW      44.500     17.882   2.489   0.0676 .
```

Hence,

$\text{F & Non W} \,= \text{In'cpt} = 70.5$

$\text{M & Non W} = \text{In'cpt} + \text{sexM} = 70.5+39.5=110$

$\text{F & W} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \,\,= \text{In'cpt} + \text{bgW} =70.5+ 16=86.5$

$\text{M & W}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \text{In'cpt} +\text{sexM}+ \text{bgW} +\text{sexM:bgW} =70.5+39.5+16+44.5= 170.5$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. Is this not regression with numerical predictors? In my case, I have factors/categoricals. I was under the impression that the model fit should be different because what's the interpretation of your fit? What I am interested in is the mean value of each product factor group (so, if we have gender and race as factors, then I am interested in the mean parameters of (black, female), (black,male), (white, female), etc... So the fit I want is $Y_i = \beta_i$ where $i$ is one of the product factors.

Comment: OK. Let me review, see if we can get it right.

Comment: I actually do know how to get that fit, mind you, by manually constructing it, but I find it weird that this is not the natural result of $lm$ when using the product operator.

Comment: @AntoniParellada `wt` and `qsec` are numeric valued predictors in this case, where the `*` is just the arithmetic product.  I believe the OP is asking about categorical/factor predictors.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Matthew, I reviewed accordingly, but leaving the original example with continuous variables.

Comment: Good specific example that illustrates the specifics of my general discussion. +1.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Nicely done.